# App crashes after I made changes to it

Tags: android

My app was running fine until today i made some changes and im getting forced close.

Here is the logcat

```
     03-20 21:11:05.441: D/dalvikvm(515): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 95K, 51% free 2680K/5379K, external 2037K/2137K, paused 75ms
03-20 21:11:06.070: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.080: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
   03-20 21:11:06.080: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because      it      is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.080: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.080: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.110: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.110: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.110: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.121: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.121: W/ResourceType(515): Skipping entry 0x7f02000f in package table 0 because it is not complex!
03-20 21:11:06.170: D/AndroidRuntime(515): Shutting down VM
03-20 21:11:06.170: W/dalvikvm(515): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.indianic.demo.calendark/com.indianic.demo.calendark.Abc}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at com.indianic.demo.calendark.Abc.onCreate(Abc.java:221)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-20 21:11:06.190: E/AndroidRuntime(515):  ... 11 more
03-20 21:11:08.470: I/Process(515): Sending signal. PID: 515 SIG: 9
```

here is the java code  http://www.mediafire.com/view/?ud3lizq4kduz1dc
im unable to upload code here

Thank You @codeMagic  the prob was with the button5 comment :)

Comment: can you provide java code?

Comment: And indicate this line `Abc.java:221`

Comment: This is not a question, this is a request for debug.

Comment: I think to help you out here, we'll need more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the initialization for `button5` commented out line 72

```
  //button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
```

uncomment that line and the `button` won't be `null`

When you look at your logcat you see

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

look for the first line that references your file which happens to be

```
at com.indianic.demo.calendark.Abc.onCreate(Abc.java:221)
```

and this tells you that something is `null` at line 221 of `ABC.java`. You can always look here and try to figure out what and why it is `null` which will make your debugging a lot faster. Hope this helps